# What is a differetial structure, exactly?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

A structure in general is a set and some operations on that set or ordersrelations of some kind.

In algebra and topology this is rather clear, but in differential geometry one often consider "differential structure".

I understand that an atlas is related to this matter and my impression is that an atlas induces a differential structure. But what is this structure?

In topology we can relate the structure to continuity i.e any topological space space that has the same topological structure also have the same continuous functions(even if it is not defined on the exact same sets). Hence one would think that differential structure and differentiable functions have the same dynamics.

Something tells me this is related to the tangent spaces and how they look as linear spaces since this is what the atlas induces at each point via the partials of the charts.

Does anyone have  good answer for what the differential structure consists of or how to think about it? Two different manifolds with different atlases should be able to have the same "differential structure" as far as I understand.

Comment: A differential structure is the same as an atlas, or more precisely a maximum atlas. It says what functions defined on the manifold are smooth in the same sense that a topology says what functions are continuous.

Comment: @DanteGrevino hence it is wrong of me to consider it a more abstract notion? such an group? where two groups can be "algebraically equal" but still very different. A counterexample would be two different familes of charts(atlases) inducing the same differential structure. As long as the bases of the tanget spaces are kind of "similar" I suppose we would get similar differential structure, but that might not be the case.

Comment: Your description of the concept of a "structure" seems to have been imported from algebra. That's not the only concept of "structure" in mathematics. Indeed, mathematicians are willing to accept very different kinds of structure in different branches of mathematics.

Comment: Just like two groups can be *isomorphic* without being equal, two differentialble manifolds can be *diffeomorphic* without being equal. The common ground here is the existence of a structure preserving map: a map of groups $f : G \to K$ is an isomorphism if it is a bijection *and* it preserves the group structure (the binary operation and the inversion); a map $f : M \to N$ of differentiable manifold is a difffeomorphism if it is a bijection *and* it preserves the differentiable structure (the pullback of an atlas of $N$ is an atlas of $M$).

Comment: @LeeMosher I was afraid that might be the case.. stated here ; en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure

Comment: Nowhere in that link provided does it restrict the concept of a structure to be a set and some operations or relations.

Comment: @LeeMosher I am not saying it contradicts you. "However" might been a poor choice of word. Fixed now.

Comment: Do you know that every atlas is included in a unique maximal atlas? So if we define a differential structure as a maximal atlas then two atlas $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ define the same differential structure if they define the same maximal atlas, which is equivalent to $\mathcal{A}_1\cup\mathcal{A_2}$ is an atlas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Definitions:**

*Definition*: Let $n$ be a non-negative integer number and let $M$ be a topological space. We say that $M$ is a *topological $n$-manifold* if it satisfies the following axioms.

1) $M$ is Hausdorff.

2) $M$ is second-countable, that is, there exists an at most countable basis for the topology.

3) $M$ is locally euclidean, that is, for every point $p$ in $M$ and every open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ there exists an homeomorphism $\varphi : V \to W$, where $V$ is an open neightborhood of $p$ contained in $U$ and $W$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In such case, a pair $(\varphi,V)$, where $\varphi:V\to W$ is an homeomorphism from an open set $V$ of $M$ to an open set $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is called a *chart* of $M$.

*Remark*: For $n=0$, we agree $\mathbb{R}^0=\{0\}$ is a singleton endowed with the unique possible topology so a topological $0$-manifold is the same as an at most countable discrete space.

*Definition*: A smooth *atlas*, or more briefly an atlas, on a topological $n$-manifold $M$ is a set $\mathcal{A} = \{(\varphi_j,V_j)\mid j\in J\}$ of charts of $M$ that satisfy the following conditions.

1) The set $\{V_j\mid j\in J\}$ is an open cover of $M$, that is, $\cup_{j\in J}V_j=M$.

2) For every $i$ and $j$ in $J$ such that $V_i\cap V_j\neq\emptyset$ we have that $\varphi_i\circ \varphi_j^{-1} : \varphi_j(V_i\cap V_j)\to \varphi_i(V_i\cap V_j)$ is smooth, that is, infinitely differentiable.

*Remark*: Given a topological $n$-manifold $M$ such that there exists an smooth atlas on it, we can consider the poset (partial ordered set) of the set of atlas on $M$ ordered by inclusion.

*Definition*: A smooth $n$-manifold is a pair $(M,\mathcal{A})$, where $M$ is a topological $n$-manifold and $\mathcal{A}$ is a maximal smooth atlas on $M$.

*Lemma*: Let $M$ be a topological $n$-manifold. For every smooth atlas $\mathcal{A}$ on $M$ there exists a unique maximal atlas $\mathcal{A}^{\text{max}}$ on $M$ containing $\mathcal{A}$. Given two smooth atlas $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ on $M$ we have that $\mathcal{A}_1^{\text{max}}=\mathcal{A}^{\text{max}}_2$ if and only if $\mathcal{A}_1\cup\mathcal{A}_2$ is an atlas.

For a *proof* see Proposition 1.17 in [Lee](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9781441999818).

*Definition*: A ***differential structure*** on a topological $n$-manifold $M$ is a maximal atlas $\mathcal{A}$ on $M$. We say that two atlas $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ on $M$ determine the same differential structure if $\mathcal{A}_1^{\text{max}}=\mathcal{A}^{\text{max}}_2$.

**Comments:**

1) If you like to adopt an algebraic point of view, we could compare the properties of the poset of atlas on a topological manifold with the poset of topologies on a set and they are very different.

2) The atlas on manifolds say what functions between manifolds are smooth in the same sense that topologies say what functions between topological spaces are continuous. Smooth manifolds and smooth functions form a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) and the same is true for topological spaces and continuous functions. In a category we have a notion of isomorphism which says that two objects are equivalent and, as @LeeMosher pointed out in the comments, in many cases it admits an interpretation in terms of preserving the structure. In the first case, an isomorphism is a diffeomorphism and, in the second case, it is an homeomorphism.

Comment: Definition: A differential structure on a topological n-manifold M is $a$ maximal atlas A on M.... I think you missed an $a$ there, or adding it increases readability atleast imo.

Comment: Also in comment 2 I think we want maximal atlases when we consider differentiability? or is the concept relevant for non maximal once?

Comment: Yes, I missed an "a". Fixed! The point with the fact that every atlas determines a unique differential structure is it allow us to define and talk about a differential structure without worry about the maximal one. We are not able to exhibit a maximal atlas, it is just a theorical concept, but we are able to exhibit an atlas, for example a finite one, in concrete examples.

Comment: Yea, not the finest moment of Zorns Lemma,right? or do we use somthing else when we conclude existance?

Comment: What about a NONCOMMUTATIVE differential structure ? does it exist ?